# ¿Cómo le digo al plugin select2 qué elemento poner seleccionado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Tengo un select con las siguientes opciones:

```
<select id="miLista">
  <option value="1">Opcion1</option>
  <option value="2">Opcion2</option>
  <option value="3">Opcion3</option>
</select>
```

Procedo a aplicarle el plugin:

```
$(#miLista).select2();
```

En algún punto de la ejecución, quiero decirle a select2 que me ponga seleccionada una opción, por ejemplo la opción 2, en otro punto la opción 3, etc.

Con JavaScript no puedo porque el plugin toma el control del select. En la documentación no encontré algo que me ayude.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Teniendo este código HTML:

```
<select id="miLista">
<option value="1">Opcion1</option>
<option value="2">Opcion2</option>
<option value="3">Opcion3</option>
</select>
```

Y este codigo JS:

```
$('#miLista').select2();
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es realizar la siguiente llamada:

```
 $('#miLista').val('2').trigger('change.select2');
```

En val() tienes que poner el valor de la lista que quieres seleccionar.

Te he dejado un ejemplo [aquí](http://codepen.io/cgardev/pen/GWxGOG)

Saludos :)

Comment: Muchas gracias cgardev, sí me funcionó :D

Comment: Buen día, Puedes poner $('#miLista').select2('val',2); Así se ve mas limpio el código.